# Laravel query builder - how to filter by relationship field

Tags: laravel

For the sake of example, say I have the following, where there is a relationship set up for each person having one hat.

```
$people = People::join('hat')->get();
```

How do I filter my results to only give me the people whose hats are red?

I have tried,

```
$people = People::join('hat')
    ->where('hat.colour', 'red')
    ->get();
```

...but no luck so far.

Cheers

Comment: Is `Hat` a Model? Does `People` have a relationship to `Hat`? If you, you can use `->whereHas()` to filter. Show your Models if you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
$people = People::whereHas('hat', function($query) {
    $query->where('colour', 'red');
})->get();
```

Comment: Hi thanks it helped alot, But i dont underestand something.. when i use it similar to laravel document and type Builder before $query, it wont work and the query is again the parent not the child. Do you know about this behavior? here is a link to an example from docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence